# Relationship between $p$-capacity and Riesz $s$-capacity of a set

Tags: reference-request, fa.functional-analysis, measure-theory, sobolev-spaces, geometric-measure-theory

What is the relationship between the definitions of $s$-capacity (page 13 [here](https://www.math.unipd.it/%7Emonti/PAPERS/Frequency2012.pdf)) and $p$-capacity ([here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/376928/the-definition-of-p-capacity-of-a-set-a-subset-mathbbrn)) of a set?

Are they equivalent? If not, what inequalities hold? What is the difference (in terms of applications) between them?

---

For convenience of the reader:

- **s-capacity**
  Define $$I_s(\mu) = \int \int |x-y|^{-s} d\mu(x) d\mu(y).$$
  If $A\subset\mathbb{R}^n$ we define the quantity
  $$
  \mathrm{Cap}_s(A) = \sup \left\{I_s(\mu)^{-1}: \mu \text{ is a finite radon measure on $A$ and } \mu(A) = 1\right\} 
  $$
  as the $s$-capacity of $A$.
- **p-capacity**
  Fix $1\leq p<n$. Define,
  \begin{equation}
  K^p\equiv\{f:\mathbb{R}^n \rightarrow \mathbb{R}\ \vert\ f\geq 0, f\in L^{p^{\ast}}(\mathbb{R}^n), Df\in L^{p}(\mathbb{R}^n;\mathbb{R}^n)\}.
  \end{equation}
  If $A\subset\mathbb{R}^n$ we define the quantity
  \begin{equation}
  \text{Cap}_p(A)    \equiv   \inf\left\{\int_{\mathbb{R}^n}\vert Df\vert^p\text{ d}x\ \middle|\   f\in K^p, A\subset\text{int}\{f\geq 1\}\right\}
  \end{equation}
  as the $p$-capacity of $A$.