# Is the graph of a Sobolev function path connected?

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, real-analysis, sobolev-spaces

Let $\Omega$ be a bounded, open, simply connected subset of $\mathbb R^n$ with Lipschitz boundary.

> **Question:** Does every function in the Sobolev space $W^{1,1} (\Omega)$
> admit a representative whose graph in $\Omega \times \mathbb R$ has a
> path connected component whose projection to $\Omega$ has full measure in $\Omega$?

Comment: I would check Evans and Gariepy. [The answer by Hajlasz here](https://mathoverflow.net/a/327703/3948) mentions a theorem in "Approach 1" which comes very close to what you want.

Comment: ACL ("absolutely continuous on lines") characterisation of weakly differentiable functions should do the job, should it not?

Comment: Oh, I suppose so - with the newest stipulation that there needs to only be a full measure path connected component, then ACL should work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As pointed out by Mateusz Kwaśnicki, the answer is yes.

Applying the ACL characterisation of Sobolev functions (see, for example page 36 here: [https://math.aalto.fi/~jkkinnun/files/sobolev_spaces.pdf](https://math.aalto.fi/%7Ejkkinnun/files/sobolev_spaces.pdf)) to each of the coordinates successively, we obtain a full measure subset $S$ of $\Omega$ whereby any two points in the graph of $f$ over $S$ are joined by the graphs of at most $n$ absolutely continuous functions (that are parallel to the coordinate axes). So in particular the graph over $S$ is path connected, as required.